# How to limit the traffic throughput ss7 with RestComm SMSC Gateway?

Tags: restcomm

I'm using RestComm SMSC Gateway 7.1.71  and I'm asking about how to limit throughput on ss7 networks (SMS/Second)

Where can I set the limit? By analogy with the smpp connector (RateLimitPerSecond)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

did you check the documentation ? See http://documentation.telestax.com/core/smsc/SMSC_Gateway_Admin_Guide.html#_esme_settings_create_cli for SMPP and http://documentation.telestax.com/core/ss7/SS7_Stack_User_Guide.html#_technical_notes for SS7 ?

Comment: I do not have a problem with the smpp (I have configured ratelimit-second for the ESME) I just want to limit the number of sendRoutingInfoForSM per second, for example, the number of SRI per second should not exceed 100 per second?